# RabbitMQ clustering in Fargate?

Tags: rabbitmq, aws-fargate, rabbitmq-cluster

I have a rabbitmq 3.9.24 instance running in Fargate behind an NLB to terminate TLS.  Seems to work okay.

I'd like to add 2 instances to set it up as a cluster.  There seem to be ways to do this in the EC2 backed ECS with autoscaling groups, and it seems like there are ways to do it in EKS, but what about Fargate?

We can't change to AmazonMQ's offering of rabbitmq.  Our code uses quorum queues, which are explictly not supported by AmazonMQ, and the devs insist this feature is a requirement.

Comment: If you know how to do this with EC2 backed ECS, and with EKS, what specifically about those solutions are you having trouble porting to Fargate backed ECS? Please add some details to your question.

Comment: Were you able to make any progress with this?

Comment: No I gave up on the ECS method, there was a lot of strangeness with DNS that I didn't want to deal with.  The EKS solution is supposed to be more out of the box but I haven't had time to explore it yet.  I just went with traditional EC2 instances in an ASG with lifecycle events, works well enough for now.  Hopefully we can get our devs to move to SQS or something else we don't have to spend time maintaining.